# Can AddressSanitizer be used to log malloc calls?

Tags: c++, linux, heap-memory, address-sanitizer

The RAM of my c++ program increases steadily, however these allocations are not leaks as they are tidied up properly when the program terminates (I get no leaks reported from AddressSanitizer). I am using a third party lib, where I cannot see the source code and I am suspecting the allocations to come from there. Can I use AddressSanitizer somehow to log all malloc calls, similar to perf record? I cannot use perf and valgrind.

Comment: In linux, you could likely *shadow* malloc, because it is a weak symbol in libc. This means, make a tiny lib that exposes a definition of malloc that logs and then calls real malloc. In linux you would use LD_PRELOAD to make ld prioritize this lib and grab this definition of malloc when dynamically linking your program

Answer (score 0):

AddressSanitizer logs all `malloc` calls but it will report leaks only for allocations which are *unreachable* i.e. when their addresses are not present anywhere in stack, global memory or reachable heap. As it does not report errors in your case, it most likely means that third-party allocations are `free`d or not done via `malloc` (e.g. via `mmap`).